# Find election winner and margin for each district in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of US House election results (general and primary) covering several decades, with the relevant columns arranged like this:

```
reprex <- tibble::tribble(
  ~candidate, ~district,  ~party, ~candvote, ~totalvote,
      "Able",        1L,   "Dem",       60L,       100L,
     "Baker",        1L,   "Rep",       40L,       100L,
   "Charlie",        2L, "Green",       25L,       100L,
       "Dog",        2L,   "Dem",       35L,       100L,
      "Easy",        2L,   "Rep",       40L,       100L
  )
```

In most cases, the winner will achieve a majority (> 50% of votes cast), but quite often will win with only a plurality (as in District 2 in the tribble).

There may (in primaries, obviously, will) be more than one candidate from the same party - eg, in California, where they operate 'top two' primaries.

What I want to do is:

- flag the winning candidate for each election in each district
- post the winning margin against that candidate.

I don't care about the format - if it's another dataframe, that's fine.

I've given some thought to how to do this, but made no headway to speak of. In SQL (of which I have some understanding, but too little to help here!), I suspect it might involve a subquery to filter down to the particular district.

And/or map to iterate the process?

I've not come across a data shape like this before, so I'm really flummoxed.

Any help gratefully accepted (if possible, in tidyverse).

Comment: what do you mean by winning margin?

Comment: You should demonstrate WITH CODE that you have a grasp of basic operation of grouping and ranking. Otherwise this is just a ‘do my project for me’.  Those are not considered on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, just need to scope what is an winner and use it inside mutate

```r
library(tidyverse)
reprex <- tibble::tribble(
  ~candidate, ~district,  ~party, ~candvote, ~totalvote,
  "Able",        1L,   "Dem",       60L,       100L,
  "Baker",        1L,   "Rep",       40L,       100L,
  "Charlie",        2L, "Green",       25L,       100L,
  "Dog",        2L,   "Dem",       35L,       100L,
  "Easy",        2L,   "Rep",       40L,       100L
)

reprex |> 
  group_by(district) |> 
  mutate(winner = party[which.max(candvote)],
         winner_perc = candvote[which.max(candvote)]/sum(candvote),
         winning_margin = winner_perc - (nth(candvote,n = 2)/sum(candvote)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 8
#> # Groups:   district [2]
#>   candidate district party candvote totalvote winner winner_perc winning_margin
#>   <chr>        <int> <chr>    <int>     <int> <chr>        <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 Able             1 Dem         60       100 Dem            0.6         0.2   
#> 2 Baker            1 Rep         40       100 Dem            0.6         0.2   
#> 3 Charlie          2 Green       25       100 Rep            0.4         0.0500
#> 4 Dog              2 Dem         35       100 Rep            0.4         0.0500
#> 5 Easy             2 Rep         40       100 Rep            0.4         0.0500
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Great - that sees me on my way. Many thanks for the quick response!